# What kind of ticket is required to travel to other zones having Nuremberg periodical ticket for tariff A?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, germany, bavaria, nuremberg

I'm really lost trying to understand the tariff for Nuremberg (Nürnberg) public transport. This is the most complicated thing I've ever met. 10 tariff zones and a dozen of ticket zone variants...

Let's say I'd buy a periodical (weekly for example) ticket for Tariff A (zones 100 and 200, Nürnberg, Fürth and Stein). What ticket do I need if on single day I'd like to travel to, let's say, Erlangen (zone 400, zone 300 is crossed).

If I'm going to stay there the whole day and use multiple buses etc., do I need to buy daily ticket for 4 zones, or can I buy some kind of supplemental ticket for zones 300 and 400 (because I already have the ticket for zones 100 and 200)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that is not the cheapest option, but I would definitely recommend you to take a S-bahn to Erlangen and then a day ticket for Erlangen area. You would pay for 2 single tickets on S-Bahn and a day pass for Erlangen (3,80 euros). Maybe if you have both a Nürnberg weekly pass and an Erlangen pass it might be enough for the S-bahn ride.

I think the idea overall is that you're not supposed to use both Erlangen and Nürnberg network on a daily basis, I mean they are probably supposed to be 2 different networks using the same tickets, same name, ...

You can still go to any office, the Nürnberg main station for example, and ask if they have specific offers.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but the problem is still relevant.

If you already have a ticket for Zone 100 and 200 you can buy a "Streifenkarte" (https://vag.tickeos.de/index.php/product/34/show/0/0/0/0) and stamp one strip for each zone.

Example: You already have a ticket for The zones 100 and 200 and you want to go to Erlangen by train, you have to stamp two strips (you cross zone 300 and 400).

But if you go by bus from Nuremburg Thon, you do not cross Zone 300, you go directly from zone 200 into 400. Then you need only on strip in addition to your 100 and 200 card.

Important: You have to stamp for every trip (except those trips happen within 1.5 h after you stamped).